# Highcharts: How to change colors of all areas except hovered one on MouseOver event in area plot

Tags: highcharts, hover, mouseover

How I can change colors of all areas except hovered one on MouseOver event in area plot?

This is doesn't work

```
var colors_grey = ["#eeeeee", "#e3e3e3","#e5e5e5", "#e6e6e6","#ededed", "#ececec"];

...

mouseOver: function () {
   var serie = this.chart.series;
   $.each(serie, function (i, e) {
        this.graph.attr({
            fill:  colors_grey[i],
            fillColor: colors_grey[i],
            stroke:  colors_grey[i]
        });
    });

    this.graph.attr({
        fillColor:  this.color
    });
}
```

And how I can fit dataLabels inside markers?

http://jsfiddle.net/cms5Lrdv/12/  (image how it should be - inside)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use `this.area` not `this.graph`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/cms5Lrdv/23/

```
                mouseOver: function () {
                   var self = this,
                       serie = this.chart.series;
                   $.each(serie, function (i, e) {
                       if(this != self) {
                           this.area.attr({
                               fill:  colors_grey[i],
                               fillColor: "#ff0000",
                               stroke:  "#ff0000",
                           });
                       } else {
                           this.area.attr({
                               fill:  "orange",
                               fillColor: "#ff0000",
                               stroke:  "#ff0000",
                           });   
                       }
                    });

                },
```